# How can i create a page that tailors personal info to the user

Tags: php, html, user-interface

After hours of trial and error, using WAMP i made a login system that mails me locally ( password recovery etc). I want to make pages that only the user has information tailored to the user, think of it as a profile page Facebook or Twitter, the news updates.

Comment: Can you please paste some code so we can help you?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, your code will guide us to select a good solution for you. Normally you would check credentials, using a session or something similar, before rendering a page.

Comment: A "user interface" is the web page itself that the user interacts with.  It sounds like what you're looking for is an authentication and/or authorization system.  A Google search for "PHP authentication" should get you started.

Comment: "i made a login system" so use that so "if not logged in redirect to login page"

Comment: Thanks guys, i know my questions is a little broad but these comments put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessions. In php you can type `session_start()`, then you can store some information about the user. So if the user don't have a session he can't access the page. Search about session_start(). You will find many examples about it.